# editing occurrences is not working

Tags: ios

i am trying to get the path to a certain file
and then open it in a webview. so i need to replace each space by '%20'

```
NSString *test=@"filename";
NSString *finalPath12 = [test stringByAppendingString:@".pdf"];

NSString *path1 = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
NSString *finalPath1 = [path1 stringByAppendingPathComponent:finalPath12];

NSString *file =@"file://";
NSString *htmlfilename1 = [file stringByAppendingString:finalPath1];

NSString *pathtofile = [htmlfilename1 stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"%20"];
```

any string is working except @"%20".

this works perfectly for exemple:

> NSString *pathtofile = [htmlfilename1 stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" "        withString:@"string"];

but i need the @"%20". What am i missing ? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is already `[NSString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:]` ([reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding%3a)) for that very purpose.

However in your case, as you want a URL, you can replace all the lines in your question with:

```
NSURL *url = [[NSBundle mainBundle] urlForResource:@"filename" withExtension:@"pdf"];
```

Comment: Thank you . But i tried writing .   NSString *stringutl = [htmlfilename1 stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]; and it didn't work

Comment: @George OK let me give a complete example.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `@"%%20"`.

As first % is treated as escape/wild character.

Or use

```
stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:
```

Comment: Another name change Anoop?  I like your film star picture better :)

Comment: @trojanfoe: This is my real pic and name, I changed my name and pic to avoid down votes as someone targeted me.

Comment: Who was the film star?  I suspected it wasn't you but don't know enough about Indian celebs to know who it was.

Comment: That was John Abramhim. :)

Comment: OK cheers.  BTW I'm pretty sure your first answer is incorrect as `%` shouldn't have any special meaning outside of a *format* method.

Comment: Then no need of second answer as you have mentioned. Do deleting this answer ;(

Comment: Hang on; Wikipedia says John Abramhim's first film was called Jism!  Yickes!  bad title...

Comment: That is an awesome movie, story is how a bad lady traps john and rest you can read it in wiki :)

Comment: I might try and get it if there is no dancing in it ;-)  I am a man of mystery...

Comment: Why dont you make more mystery by wriing i am 6 yrs old having developed thousands of ios app. With many websites and few OSs, as i see in few profiles :D

Comment: @George : Did my answer work? And let me know which one of two. I was going to delete this one :p

Comment: I have seen in one profile having 5K+ points from India :( When i was 6, i was knowing about calculators and typewriters, and often went to my dad's office to see telephone!!!